# Angular provide an observable that does something whenever it is called

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have a provider called `UserProvider`, which exposes an Angular http observable that updates user on the server such as the following:

```
export class UserProvider = {
  user: User;

  update(params): Observable<User> {
    return this.http.patch<User>(`${API_ENDPOINT}/users/this.user.id`, params);
  }
}
```

Now, the http `patch` request returns the updated user on the server. I would like to assign that to `this.user` every time the `update()` observable is executed.

Note that I'm not looking for updating the user on the caller's side. I would like to expose an observable that does so automatically whenever it is subscribed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `pipe`  your request and using `tap` operator assign the response to the `user` property. This will make a chain, you can still subscribe to the observable, but now every time `this.user = response` will be executed.

```
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

export class UserProvider = {
  user: User;

  update(params): Observable<User> {
    return this.http.patch<User>(`${API_ENDPOINT}/users/this.user.id`, params)
                    .pipe(tap(response => this.user = response));
  }
}
```

Comment: This is awesome. Thanks!